# Generate from two ruby arrays an appropriate JSON output

Tags: arrays, ruby, json

I have two simple ruby arrays and a JSON string mapping the elements of the first array to the elements of the second array:

```
keys = [:key0, :key1, :key2]
values = [:value0, :value1, :value2]

jsonString = {keys[0] => values[0], keys[1] => values[1], keys[2] => values[2]}
```

Writing this to a file:

```
file.write(JSON.pretty_generate(jsonString))
```

results into a nicely printed json object:

```
{
    "key0": "value0",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

But how can I generate the same output of two much bigger arrays without listing all these elements explicitly?

I just need something like

```
jsonString = {keys => values}
```

but this produces a different output:

```
{
    "[:key0, :key1, :key2]":
    [
        "value0",
        "value1",
        "value2"
    ]
}
```

How can I map the two without looping over both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array#zip` to make pairs of values and then make hash of them:

```
keys = [:key0, :key1, :key2]
values = [:value0, :value1, :value2]
Hash[keys.zip values]
# => {:key0=>:value0, :key1=>:value1, :key2=>:value2}
```

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = keys.zip(values)
#=> [[:key0, :value0], [:key1, :value1], [:key2, :value2]]
```

[Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) merges elements of self to the corresponding elements of the argument array and you get an array of arrays. This you can convert into a hash ...

```
hash = array.to_h
# => {:key0=>:value0, :key1=>:value1, :key2=>:value2}
```

... and the hash you can turn into a json string.

```
jsonString = JSON.pretty_generate(hash)
puts jsonString
#{
#  "key0": "value0",
#  "key1": "value1",
#  "key2": "value2"
#}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!